# multiple select box using v-for

Tags: vue.js

I have multiple select boxes which are rendered using a v-for loop, what I am trying to do is to store each option value for each select box in an array but when I select an option it only stores the chosen option, not multiple options

```
 <template v-for="(gettailor) in gettailors" :key="gettailor.id">

                      <div class="col-sm-6" >
                           <div class="form-floating" >
                                 <p>{{ gettailor.names }}</p>
                            </div>




                      </div>



                      <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <div class="form-floating">
                            <select   class="form-select shadow-none" id="tailors"  v-model="tailors"   required>

                                <template v-for="(item) in gettailor.tailor" :key="item.id">

                                <option :value="item.id">{{ item.tailor }}</option>

                                </template>
                            </select>

                            <label for="tailors">Choose {{ gettailor.names }}</label>
                        </div>

                      </div>




                    </template>

    <script>
  import { ref, watch,onMounted } from 'vue';
 const tailors = ref([]);

   </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `tailors` should be an object, then you bind the select value to a value in the object:

```
<select
  class="form-select shadow-none"
  id="tailors[]"            <-------- generates several selects with same id 
  v-model="tailors[gettailor.id]"  <--------- bind to object value
  required
>
```

Of course you can also use an array, but it does not work well with reactivity if you use loop index as key (if order changes, you don't know where the values came from), and if you use tailor id, you get a sparse array, which is probably hard to work with.

Comment: thank you its working but it shows the first value null in an array [ null, 45, 47, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53 ]

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean it wont work well with reactivity

Comment: @Martín Updated the answer, my guess is that as a result, you want to have a number of tailor ids and for each a selected items. Use what works better for you, but an object is probably going to give you better service, as it is closer to what you want to express.

Comment: Thank you so much do you have any reference on how to use object as I am new in vue

Comment: Oh, I just mean a regular JS object `const tailors = {}`. Though you probably want to make it reactive, so that vue can detect changes to it. How to do that depends on your Vue version and which declaration style you prefer. In general, you declare the object as part the components [data props](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html). In Vue 2, you also have to add properties not declared during initialization with [`Vue.set()`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects). That's the gist, but you can easily find tons of details about it.